# Calculating the file offset of a entry point in a PE file

Tags: windows, assembly, portable-executable

In

http://en.redinskala.com/finding-the-ep/

there is information about how to find the file offset of the entry point in a exe-file.

Here I can read that

> EP (File) = AddressOfEntryPoint – BaseOfCode + .text[PointerToRawData]
>   + FileAlignment

However, when I have been calculating this myself (I used a couple of different exe files) I have came to the conclusion that

> Offset of entry point in EXE file = AddressOfEntryPoint + .text[PointerToRawData] -
>   .text[VirtualAddress]

Where AddressOfEntryPoint is fetched from IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER and the other two values from the IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER.

Is the information on that web page false? Adding FileAlignment like they do just seems wrong, it does not make sense. Or does it? A file alignment suggests that I should use modulo or something to compute a value. If BaseOfCode and FileAlignment is the same value (mostly they are), it would not disturb adding them to the calculation, but how would it make sense?

Comment: I'd have to reread the PE spec, but adding file alignment seems wrong indeed. If the unaligned offset is `x`, I'd go for `x - x % FileAlignment`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Correct, you don't need to use the `FileAlignment` value at all.

The algorithm should be something like as follow (very similar to yours):

- Get `AddressOfEntryPoint` from IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER.AddressOfEntryPoint (this is a VA)
- Search in which section header this VA resides (usually the 1st one, but you should really search in all section headers).
- Once you have the right section header, get its `VirtualAddress` and `PointerToRawData` fields.
- Subtract `VirtualAddress` from `AddressOfEntryPoint`: you now have a "delta"
- As the exactly same delta applies to offsets, then: add "delta" to `PointerToRawData`.

You simply don't need `FileAlignment` because the section in which the entry point lies is already aligned on that value.